# Set jsonp proxy url dynamically in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I like to set the proxy url dynamically before calling load() method of store as its like to append dynamic variable to URL can any oen help me out to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get proxy from your store and then change the url of that proxy.

```
var yourStore= Ext.getStore('storename');
var proxy = yourStore.getProxy();
proxy.setUrl("new Url");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response ,here storename would be store class name right?

Comment: I got below exception for the code below
07-03 19:06:26.230: D/CordovaLog(4981): file:///android_asset/www/app.js: Line 1 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getProxy' of undefined


var yourStore= Ext.getStore('StationStore');
    var proxy = yourStore.getProxy();
    proxy.setUrl(Config.URL_STATION +SyncHistoryController.FacilitySyncDateTime);

Comment: Its working fine we have to pass store xtype in storename for Ext.getStore('storename'); Able to get get the udpated proxy url by using proxy.getUrl() but unabel to impact the updated url in store.load()